# Vuforia iOS fit video inside target

Tags: ios, objective-c, vuforia

I was trying to create combination of `cloud recognition` and `video playback` using `Vuforia`. I can't make it to fit video inside target. Target's on Vuforia website have width set to about 300, and I think, a need to prepare renderFrameWithState function correctly, but I don't know how. Basically, I would like the video to fit inside target, ignoring it's size on website, but keeping video aspect ratio. Can someone help me with this?

```
- (void)renderFrameWithState:(const Vuforia::State &)state projectMatrix:(Vuforia::Matrix44F &)projectionMatrix
{
    [self setFramebuffer];

    // Clear colour and depth buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Render the video background
    [sampleAppRenderer renderVideoBackground];

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // We must detect if background reflection is active and adjust the culling
    // direction.  If the reflection is active, this means the pose matrix has
    // been reflected as well, therefore standard counter clockwise face culling
    // will result in "inside out" models
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    // Get the active trackables
    int numActiveTrackables = state.getNumTrackableResults();

    // ----- Synchronise data access -----
    [dataLock lock];

    // Assume all targets are inactive (used when determining tap locations)
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumVideoTargets; ++i) {
        videoData[i].isActive = NO;
    }

    tapProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    // Did we find any trackables this frame?
    for (int i = 0; i < numActiveTrackables; ++i) {
        // Get the trackable
        const Vuforia::TrackableResult* trackableResult = state.getTrackableResult(i);
        const Vuforia::ImageTarget& imageTarget = (const Vuforia::ImageTarget&) trackableResult->getTrackable();

        // VideoPlayerHelper to use for current target
        int playerIndex = 0;    // stones

        self.currentMediaID = [NSString stringWithCString:imageTarget.getUniqueTargetId() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        // Mark this video (target) as active
        videoData[playerIndex].isActive = YES;

        // Get the target size (used to determine if taps are within the target)
        if (0.0f == videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0] ||
            0.0f == videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[1]) {
            const Vuforia::ImageTarget& imageTarget = (const Vuforia::ImageTarget&) trackableResult->getTrackable();

            Vuforia::Vec3F size = imageTarget.getSize();
            videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0] = size.data[0];
            videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[1] = size.data[1];

            // The pose delivers the centre of the target, thus the dimensions
            // go from -width / 2 to width / 2, and -height / 2 to height / 2
            videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0] /= 2.0f;
            videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[1] /= 2.0f;
        }

        // Get the current trackable pose
        const Vuforia::Matrix34F& trackablePose = trackableResult->getPose();

        // This matrix is used to calculate the location of the screen tap
        videoData[playerIndex].modelViewMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(trackablePose);

        float aspectRatio;
        const GLvoid* texCoords;
        GLuint frameTextureID = 0;
        BOOL displayVideoFrame = YES;

        // Retain value between calls
        static GLuint videoTextureID[kNumVideoTargets] = {0};

        MEDIA_STATE currentStatus = [videoPlayerHelper[playerIndex] getStatus];

        // NSLog(@"MEDIA_STATE for %d is %d", playerIndex, currentStatus);

        // --- INFORMATION ---
        // One could trigger automatic playback of a video at this point.  This
        // could be achieved by calling the play method of the VideoPlayerHelper
        // object if currentStatus is not PLAYING.  You should also call
        // getStatus again after making the call to play, in order to update the
        // value held in currentStatus.
        // --- END INFORMATION ---

        switch (currentStatus) {
            case PLAYING: {
                // If the tracking lost timer is scheduled, terminate it
                if (nil != trackingLostTimer) {
                    // Timer termination must occur on the same thread on which
                    // it was installed
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(terminateTrackingLostTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                }

                // Upload the decoded video data for the latest frame to OpenGL
                // and obtain the video texture ID
                GLuint videoTexID = [videoPlayerHelper[playerIndex] updateVideoData];

                if (0 == videoTextureID[playerIndex]) {
                    videoTextureID[playerIndex] = videoTexID;
                }

                // Fallthrough
            }
            case PAUSED:
                if (0 == videoTextureID[playerIndex]) {
                    // No video texture available, display keyframe
                    displayVideoFrame = NO;
                }
                else {
                    // Display the texture most recently returned from the call
                    // to [videoPlayerHelper updateVideoData]
                    frameTextureID = videoTextureID[playerIndex];
                }

                break;

            default:
                videoTextureID[playerIndex] = 0;
                displayVideoFrame = NO;
                break;
        }

        if (YES == displayVideoFrame) {
            // ---- Display the video frame -----
            aspectRatio = (float)[videoPlayerHelper[playerIndex] getVideoHeight] / (float)[videoPlayerHelper[playerIndex] getVideoWidth];
            texCoords = videoQuadTextureCoords;
        }
        else {
            // ----- Display the keyframe -----
            Texture* t = augmentationTexture[OBJECT_KEYFRAME_1 + playerIndex];
            frameTextureID = [t textureID];
            aspectRatio = (float)[t height] / (float)[t width];
            texCoords = quadTexCoords;
        }

        // If the current status is valid (not NOT_READY or ERROR), render the
        // video quad with the texture we've just selected
        if (NOT_READY != currentStatus) {
            // Convert trackable pose to matrix for use with OpenGL
            Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewMatrixVideo = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(trackablePose);
            NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f, %f", trackablePose.data[0], trackablePose.data[1], trackablePose.data[2], trackablePose.data[3] );
            Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewProjectionVideo;

            //            SampleApplicationUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0],
            //                                             &modelViewMatrixVideo.data[0]);

            NSLog(@"F: %f", videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0]);

            SampleApplicationUtils::scalePoseMatrix(videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0],
                                                    videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0] * aspectRatio,
                                                    videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[0],
                                                    &modelViewMatrixVideo.data[0]);

            SampleApplicationUtils::multiplyMatrix(projectionMatrix.data,
                                                   &modelViewMatrixVideo.data[0] ,
                                                   &modelViewProjectionVideo.data[0]);

            glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

            glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadVertices);
            glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadNormals);
            glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, texCoords);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureID);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&modelViewProjectionVideo.data[0]);
            glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0 /*GL_TEXTURE0*/);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, kNumQuadIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, quadIndices);

            glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            glUseProgram(0);
        }

        // If the current status is not PLAYING, render an icon
        if (PLAYING != currentStatus) {
            GLuint iconTextureID;

            switch (currentStatus) {
                case READY:
                case REACHED_END:
                case PAUSED:
                case STOPPED: {
                    // ----- Display play icon -----
                    iconTextureID = [augmentationTexture[OBJECT_PLAY_ICON] textureID];
                    break;
                }

                case ERROR: {
                    // ----- Display error icon -----
                    iconTextureID = [augmentationTexture[OBJECT_ERROR_ICON] textureID];
                    break;
                }

                default: {
                    // ----- Display busy icon -----
                    iconTextureID = [augmentationTexture[OBJECT_BUSY_ICON] textureID];
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Convert trackable pose to matrix for use with OpenGL
            Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewMatrixButton = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(trackablePose);
            Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewProjectionButton;

//            SampleApplicationUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[1] / SCALE_ICON_TRANSLATION, &modelViewMatrixButton.data[0]);
            SampleApplicationUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.01f, &modelViewMatrixButton.data[0]);

            SampleApplicationUtils::scalePoseMatrix(videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[1] / SCALE_ICON,
                                                    videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[1] / SCALE_ICON,
                                                    videoData[playerIndex].targetPositiveDimensions.data[1] / SCALE_ICON,
                                                    &modelViewMatrixButton.data[0]);

            SampleApplicationUtils::multiplyMatrix(projectionMatrix.data,
                                                   &modelViewMatrixButton.data[0] ,
                                                   &modelViewProjectionButton.data[0]);

            glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

            glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

            glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadVertices);
            glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadNormals);
            glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, quadTexCoords);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            // Blend the icon over the background
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, iconTextureID);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&modelViewProjectionButton.data[0] );
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, kNumQuadIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, quadIndices);

            glDisable(GL_BLEND);

            glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

            glUseProgram(0);

            glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
        }

        SampleApplicationUtils::checkGlError("VideoPlayback renderFrameVuforia");
    }

    // --- INFORMATION ---
    // One could pause automatic playback of a video at this point.  Simply call
    // the pause method of the VideoPlayerHelper object without setting the
    // timer (as below).
    // --- END INFORMATION ---

    // If a video is playing on texture and we have lost tracking, create a
    // timer on the main thread that will pause video playback after
    // TRACKING_LOST_TIMEOUT seconds
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumVideoTargets; ++i) {
        if (nil == trackingLostTimer && NO == videoData[i].isActive && PLAYING == [videoPlayerHelper[i] getStatus]) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createTrackingLostTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
            break;
        }
    }

    [dataLock unlock];
    // ----- End synchronise data access -----

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    [self presentFramebuffer];

}
```

Comment: any luck for this? i need help for cloud recognition + video playback for native ios. any proper tutorial or sample code available please share.